# regular expression for words with 8 or 7 characters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches words with 8 or 7 characters and includes (ea).
this is what I've got so far:

```
[\w*(ea)\w*]{7,8}
```

the problem is it also accepts the first 8 characters of "bbeabbbbbbb" but I dont want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when inside charset `[]`, brackets `(`,`)` loses its special meaning and matched literally. that's why you are getting wrong results. Try below regex.

```regex
(?=(?=(?<!\w)\w*\(ea\))[\w()]{7,8}(?:\s|$))[\w()]{7,8}
```

[Demo in regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EcDg7H/2)